# A cat with a broken leg: What will happen if it is not surgically treated?

Tags: cats, injury, surgery

My 11-month-old cat has a broken pelvis and tibia in her back paw (see photo). According to the information I received, the pelvic bone may heal on its own, but the leg bone will most likely require surgery. This means two operations will be necessary: one to fix it with an iron and another to remove the iron after healing. I am concerned about having to put my cat through two surgeries. It has been 7 days since the fracture, and he refrains from moving his leg due to the pain. He tries to find a comfortable position on his own while lying down in the cage or getting up to avoid pain. He is more active with his other leg and handles the injured leg with great care. Please, by looking at the photo, could you advise me on whether the operation is necessary? Is there a chance the bone will heal well without surgery and my cat won't be lame?

I reviewed the answers provided in the related post, but I couldn't find an exact match for the injury my cat has. As my cat's condition differs from the cases mentioned, I want to highlight the importance of an evaluation based on the X-ray picture I uploaded. The X-ray will provide crucial information to determine whether my cat might avoid surgery or if it's necessary due to the fragmented bone injury. Your insights based on the specific X-ray are highly valued. Thank you.

[image: X-ray]

Comment: This question already has an answer here: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/32831/a-cat-with-broken-leg-what-would-have-happened-if-left-unattended

Comment: I reviewed the answers provided in the related post, but I couldn't find an exact match for the injury my cat has. As my cat's condition differs from the cases mentioned, I want to highlight the importance of an evaluation based on the X-ray picture I uploaded. The X-ray will provide crucial information to determine whether my cat might avoid surgery or if it's necessary due to the fragmented bone injury. Your insights based on the specific X-ray are highly valued. Thank you.