# Why aren't leg amputations usually done right at the knee-joint? (turkey-leg style)

Tags: cats, anatomy, surgery

I've noticed that cat leg amputations aren't usually done right at the knee-joint.

For example, with my cat, the [shin bones were shattered and unrepairable](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/32820/white-opaque-shards-in-cat-leg-x-ray), so an amputation was done.

The amputation wasn't done right at the knee -- removing the damaged shin bones and beyond. Instead, the amputation was done further up the leg, up on the thigh bone.

As someone who knows nothing about medical/pet science, I'm curious why the preferred option is to cut mid-way up a good bone (like the thigh bone), rather than preserve the entire thigh bone, and amputate at the knee instead.

---

*In other words, why don't we see more amputations that have the thigh's knee socket-ball in tact? (kind of like what we'd see with a turkey leg at Thanksgiving :)*

Comment: If I remember right, then the cats real knee is where the leg "meet" the body. Cats walk on their tiptoes so the "first" bow (where humans would have a knee) is their real ankle. For clearification: what "knee" do you speak about? :) the real one or the ankle, in position of a human knee?

Comment: I posted a sister question in Medical Science Stack Exchange: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/29345/why-arent-leg-amputations-usually-done-right-at-the-knee-joint-turkey-leg-sty