# What is the purpose of a cat's heel (halfway up the leg)?

Tags: cats, anatomy

What is the purpose of a cat's heel (halfway up the leg)?

[image]

[image]

<sup>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitigrade)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From @Krupip's comment in a [related post](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/32807/do-cats-walk-on-their-tiptoes/32809#32809):

> It's a pivot point where muscles attach to.
>
> Muscles contract, causing the bone to act like a lever, pushing the
> whole foot down, allowing more force to be applied to the ground.
>
> [The
> particular leg in the diagram] represents the back leg of a dog/cat,
> the heel is extended on the blackleg to give the animal more power
> when jumping.
>
> This is good for pouncing predators, but also the only practical way
> large animals can jump with any distance, such as horses, which only
> have the pivot on the back leg and have pillar legs on the front (the
> bones are inline, there is no modified heel pivot location).

*Feel free to edit or replace this answer.*

Comment: you can accept your own answer as solved and get some extra rep,if anybody posts a better answer you can change the accepted one to the other answer if you want.

Comment: @trondhansen Yeah, thanks. When I try that, I get a message that says I have to wait for two days before accepting my own answer.

Comment: i was not sure you did know it so it was just to inform you :)